# Lucene.net HTML Document example with a string of html instead of a file?

Tags: c#, string, memory-management, lucene.net

I'm doing a web crawler and I want to use lucene to index while the streaming is progressing or completed.

I've seen that the example of lucene.net html library is good. however, I don't want to keep download into disk. what i want and is just indexing while downloading the web or maybe index of a string of html content.

Is there any example that makes lucence.net html indexer working with memory stream or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that?

```
        // create writer to index
        IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(new FileInfo("C:\\example\\"), new StandardAnalyzer());

        // create a document to index
        Document d = new Document();

        // create a field that the document will contain
        Field aField = new Field("test", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        // add the field to the document
        d.Add(aField);

        // index some data (4 documents)
        aField.SetValue("Example 1");
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        aField.SetValue("Example 2");
        iw.AddDocument(d);
        aField.SetValue("Example 3");
        iw.AddDocument(d);

        aField.SetValue("Example 4");
        // a field with Store.NO can be set with a TextReader
        Field notStored = new Field("test2", "", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        notStored.SetValue(new StringReader("Example 4 - From TextReader"));
        // add new field to a 4th document
        d.Add(notStored);
        iw.AddDocument(d);

        // closing writer commits changes to disk
        iw.Close();
```